# How to flip all the normals properly on this model?

Tags: mesh, materials, normals

this is my first time here on StackExchange. I'm pretty new to Blender but I have successfully created some simplistic models so far.
So I just modeled a roof rack made for Euro Truck Simulator 2. Since it's made out of cylinders a lot of normals need to be flipped, but doing it one by one could take hours and it's a pain.

The model with the default material:
[image]

The model with a chrome-like material, as you can see the normals are off almost everywhere:
[image]

Is it possible to flip every normal with a simplier method? Thanks in advance for the answer! :)

Comment: Wow, such fast help! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped :). Welcome to the site.